# How can I programmatically open my app's DND permision screen?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I used this code to get the DND (Do not disturb) permission from the user.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            //Permission not granted so we wiil ask for it.
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Settings
                            .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            //Permission granted
            //do something 
        }
```

but this code opens a DND permission screen of a list of apps, as in the following image:

[image: What I got]

I want to directly open my application DND permission screen, like in this image:

[image: What I want]

Help me please :)

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Ton No, I didn't. I think it is impossible :)